# Proof that no futures trading system always wins

Tags: reference-request, finance

Hopefully someone here has some knowledge in both finance and maths.

I am pondering on the existence/impossibility of a trading system (or algorithm) that ALWAYS ends up winning money, no matter how the price of a futures moves.  That is, in a context where one can buy or sell (short) to make a profit.

If the trader has infinite funds, it's possible.  He can setup some kind of martingale system and cancel every loss by making an opposite trade.

If the trader has limited funds, there's an intuitive proof that no system  can win: if it existed, someone would have figured it out by now.

But I'm looking for a formal treatment of the question.  Lots of papers deal with trading in a model in which prices movements are associated with probabilities, such as brownian movement and the like.  But really, what I'm looking for is a proof that there's no algorithm that can beat ANY price movement.  Meaning, for every trading algorithm, there exists a price movement in which the algorithm incurs a loss.  Any references on the topic is appreciated.

Comment: There is a nice book 'You can't lose trading commodities', but even that is based on the assumption of infinite funds. That's where a famous fund had imploded about 20 years back.  So this is a good question about a math proof

Comment: If you enter the financial market, you will probably discover everything you learn from school is wrong.
Traders doesn't make money from setting up any martingale.
spot traders provide liquidity to the market and earn money from the tiny bid/ask spread.
proprietary traders takes a view on the market and bet. They make money out of inefficiency of the market. Everyone is in a constant race of discovering market mis-pricing faster than the rest.

Comment: @achillehui Presumably, by asking the question here, the OP is more interested in theoretical proofs, not the real world.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, exactly !

Comment: Well, if anyone is interested, I asked the same question at quantitive finance http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22634/proof-that-no-trading-system-always-wins/22671#22671.  A lot more answers over there, but each is more confusing than the other.